# How to detect ignored return values

Tags: go

Given the following function:

```
func CreateDB() (*xorm.Engine orm, error) {

}
```

I want to detect within that function whether it was called like this:

```
_, err := CreateDB()
```

...or like this:

```
orm, err := CreateDB()
```

I want to check the `orm` variable and close the connection if it's not required. Is this possible?

Comment: No, not possible. This seems like an XY problem. What is your real goal?

Comment: Consider this: the assignment of return values happens *after the function returns*. Therefor, there would be no way at runtime for the function to know what will happen after it returns.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't do that and it is also not a good design. You can check from which function it was called using reflection and see if that function is using the orm variable or not.

https://golang.org/pkg/runtime/#Caller

Go uses connection pool and if you are worried about the open connection, you may use timeout for each connection made.